# Set products options with installer

Tags: product, product-attribute

I'm creating a new module with a multiple select attribute "size".
The attribute and it's values are created in an installer script.

How can I assign the products to the values in the installer script, for example:

`SKU shirtsummer => size =>large`
`SKU shirtwinter => size =>medium`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with the **data-install.php** (app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/data/modulename_setup/data-install-1.0.0.php )

```
$installer = $this;   
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'shirtwinter');
$_product->setSize(“large”)->save();
```

You can also look other data-install files for your reference.....